# Value Assigned Is Not Used

Tags: c#, winforms

I may be overlooking something, well obviously I am. I am using an uninitialized variable of type int (carRequired). I am utilizing this variable inside an IF statement (code below). However, I get a warning stating the variable is never used yet it is. Yes, I am aware of not being good practice to embed sql, however I am told to do it this way for now.

```
public bool UpdateDiscrepancyReport()
    {
        var errorStatus = false;
        int carRequired ;
        carRequired = cbxCarRequired.Checked == false ? 0 : 1;
        var updateQuery = "my query string ";                         
        dbf.OpenConnection(updateQuery);
        bool updateStatus = dbf.OpenConnection(updateQuery);
        if (updateStatus)
        {
            errorStatus = true;
        }
        else
        {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Error in updating DR" + tbxDRNumber.Text+@" ",@"Update Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return errorStatus;
    }
```

Comment: No, it is never used. It's assigned to, but that assignment is useless. You don't use the variable after assigning the result of the ternary expression, so you can remove those two lines altogether and not affect the functionality of the code. (You can remove the declaration of `errorstatus` and simply `return false;` instead as well, since you do nothing to affect the value of errorstatus after it's initial declaration and assignment.)

Comment: If you don't expect any *side effects* from `cbxCarRequired.Checked` the method equals to `public bool UpdateDiscrepancyReport() { dbf.OpenConnection(updateQuery); return false; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is never *used*. It is *assigned to*, but the variable is never used after that assignment; you don't do anything after assigning the result of the ternary operation to it. In fact, the variable isn't necessary at all, and neither is `errorStatus` (in the original code you posted), since you never do anything in the code that will change it's value after it is initialized.

The code you've posted (prior to your edit that added several more lines) is the exact equivalent of

```
public bool UpdateDiscrepancyReport()
    {
        dbf.OpenConnection(updateQuery);
        return false;
    }
```

The compiler is telling you that the variable declaration and assignment to `carRequired` is meaningless, because it does not affect anything in your code. Determining whether the checkbox is checked or not only has meaning if your code does something differently based on that information, and the use of  `carRequired` as written does nothing based on the value assigned;  therefore, the assignment (and variable declaration) are useless.

Comment: I was attempting to keep the code short to not have people go through several lines of it. But, I guess that isn't always a good idea. Although I don't think it will change the answer(s) too much, I will modify the initial post to reflect all the code in that code block.

Comment: That doesn't change the issue with the `carRequired` not being used. :-)

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding things today, I am still learning. What is meant by "That doesn't change the issue with the carRequired not being used"? I need to see if the check box is checked and if it is I need to assign a value of 1 or 0 if it isn't checked. Maybe I answered my own question. Using the ternary operation I am already assigning a 1 or 0 respectively depending whether the check box is checked or not. So, there isn't a need to actually create a variable for it.

Comment: That's fine, but then you  need to actually **use** that value once you've set it. In the code you posted, you're not; you're only making the assignment. The result of the ternary operation is simply discarded, so you can remove that operation entirely and not affect the outcome of the code (which is what the compiler is telling you - declaring that variable and assigning it the value does absolutely nothing). You don't need to know if the checkbox is checked or not *unless you're going  to do something based on that information, which you are not*.